# How to specify the address of the host in IPv4?

Tags: ip, network

Lets say the IPv4 address is: 192.168.50.112 /26 which provides 4 subnets

subnet mask: 255.255.255.192

network address 192.168.50.64/26

There are 6 bits left for the Host, how do you specify the host address?

Comment: You said right in your question that the host address is 192.168.50.112

Comment: Thats the IP address which contains both the network and host address

Comment: this is not a duplicate

Comment: So what is your question? You said that the host address is 192.168.50.112